# MeteorJS and IoT Space

Tags: javascript, meteor, iot, plc, codesys

I want deploy a Meteor application on a wago industrial PLC 750-8202.
Wago supports Boards Support Package with the PTXdist tooling support ([Communicate with CoDeSys program on a Linux-based WAGO PFC200 PLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030620/communicate-with-codesys-program-on-a-linux-based-wago-pfc200-plc)).
I have no idea how i can utilize meteor on such a platform.
Have you any ideas how the steps can be realized to add meteor support for wago plcs ?

Answer (score 1):

It is has linux on it, just SSH to your PLC. Make sure it is connected to your local network.

Now you can install node and everything else. It is like you have your own VPS. Configure everything. You can even install ftp server and upload your files over FTP. Or create small script that will be triggered from Github hooks and update your PLC as soon as you push changes to `master` branch.